# Application is not responding

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 20.04

I tried to install stacer Linux system optimizer and monitoring tool in 20.04 using the command `sudo apt install stacer`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
stacer is already the newest version (1.1.0-3).
```

The process successfully completed, but I got these results when I tried to start the application from the terminal

```
$ stacer
Command 'stacer' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install stacer
```

and stacer is unable to start.

Comment: DId you tried to run it as `/usr/bin/stacer` from terminal ? Also please add output of `echo $PATH` .

Answer (score 0):

I got the following message when installing stacer (version 1.1.0-3) in Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo apt install stacer`:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-inter libdouble-conversion3 libpcre2-16-0 libqt5charts5 libqt5core5a
  libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5
  libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 qt5-gtk-platformtheme qttranslations5-l10n
  stacer
```

Use the `apt policy package-name` command to check whether all of these packages are installed. If any of these packages are not installed then install them. If you get an error message in the terminal when trying to install any of these packages please post the error message in a comment or add the error message  to your question.

If this doesn't work then please post the results of `echo $PATH` in a comment.

If stacer is installed it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: The OP may have problems with PATH, I think.